# How to get user input Excel sheet and generate output.xls file in C# windows firm?

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

My goal is to create a simple (one file) executable for windows environment that will open a pretty simple form. The form will read data from with two different Excel files and submit it - the application will write the data in to output.xls Excel file.

I have posted my sample sheet in below link for your ref:

[Please click this link](http://server.myspace-shack.com/d21/makk.jpg)

1. To check whether the date is available for column C "120" from sheet1 to sheet2 based on vlookup function in excel
2. if it is not available date in sheet2 then create output for "120"

```html
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFD = new OpenFileDialog();
            //openFD.Filter = "Excel(*.xlx; *.xlsm; *.gif; *.bmp)";

            if (openFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = openFD.FileName;
            }

       }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog openFD = new OpenFileDialog();
            //openFD.Filter = "Excel(*.xlx; *.xlsm; *.gif; *.bmp)";

            if (openFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox2.Text = openFD.FileName;
            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string Import_FileName = path;
                string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(Import_FileName);
                if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Import_FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'";
                if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Import_FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
                using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    comm.CommandText = "Select * from [" + sheet1 + "$]";

                    comm.Connection = conn;

                    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {
                        da.SelectCommand = comm;
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }

                }
            }


        }
    }

}
```

please guide me to do this task.

Comment: first try something..atleast google

Comment: I have tried this but there was error in oledb connection

Comment: which conn string?.xls or .xlsx

Comment: What was the error?  whats the name of the file? is the file already open?

Comment: I am using constring .xls

Comment: I have upload button1_click for sheet1 and button2_click for sheet2 and then submit. I am trying to open sheet and check all data. No i am not open file